# Setting interbyte delay for bytes in C

Tags: c, serial-port

I am communicating with a  USB to RS232 converter, and need to send data via K line ISO14230 protocol, the data i am sending are getting overlapped and hence i need to set a interbyte delay? Any pointers on how it can be implemented?

Comment: What do you mean "getting overlapped"? How are you seeing this? How are you implementing the code?

Comment: Do you mean the receiver can't process its input quickly enough, or the transmitter isn't checking the shift register status?

Comment: KWP2000 is a protocol used in on-board vehicle diagnostic systems.  The kind of application where you'd exclusively use micro-controllers.  Control over the K-line is *very* time-critical.  Not a problem in a micro-controller, big problem in a commodity operating system.  You can't make this work, buy the hardware you need.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am sending data bytes at different baud rates and yes when i try to measure it in oscilloscope, i dont get the required waveform, i am working on implementing kwp 2000 protocol. I am using C language and win API

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please tell me what kind of Hardware do i need to buy, i already have a k2L901 USB to RS232 converter.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am able to see the databytes but they arent the one i expected , i mean the waveforms when i observe in oscilloscope.

Comment: No idea, I never bought one and you did not provide any details about the bus.  Definitely not RS-232, maybe CAN.  This isn't on topic here.

Comment: @HansPassant I am using USB to RS232 Converter K line connector, my assumption is it should work, but unfortunately not.

Comment: RS-232 is asynchronous, meaning the interframe time is unspecified.  Typically the source tries to transmit with as short a time as posible/convenient to maximize channel throughput.  If you want to control the *"interbyte delay"*, then you would need a driver that could meter the writes to the transmit register.  With USB in the middle, the timing could be rather sloppy.  You'd have better control of timing with a UART on a faster bus, e.g. on a PCI/PCIe card.